# How do you put the words of a large text file into a list

Tags: python

I have a large text file that is a book long and I want to take the words out of the text file and move them into a list.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3):

If you care about removing punctuation:

```
import re

testString = 'Word test! Hello, how are you?' 
wordList = re.findall(r'\w+', testString) 
print(wordList)
```

```
['Word', 'test', 'Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Otherwise:

```
testString = 'Word test! Hello, how are you?' 
wordList = testString.split()
print(wordList)
```

```
['Word', 'test!', 'Hello,', 'how', 'are', 'you?']
```

Answer (score 2):

first you need to open the file

```
file = open('yourfile.fmt')
```

after opening simply read all the lines

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

after that turn lines into a string with a space in between them and trim each line to remove extra whitespace.

```
from string import strip
string = ' '.join(map(strip, lines))
```

finally you can split your string and get the words

```
words = string.split()
```

if you are using it for AI or Data Science there is packages that can make your life easier like sklearn and nltk

Comment: better use a context manager to open the file